# I am trying to compare two dictionaries in Python and return the key for which values changed. But Python throws a invalid Syntax

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I am trying to compare two dictionaries based on the value and return if there are any newly added keys and removed keys. I also want to print the modified keys(if the values are changed).

Basically, i have a directory with multiple sub folders and files in it. I calculate the md5sum of all these and have similar directory on other node, check these both and print the added, removed and modified keys based on checksum.

I have written the code to do these, it works as well in Python 2.7. But sadly, i m suppposed make this work in 2.6 and lesser as well. Here is the code and it throws invalid syntax in

```
import os
import sys
from hashlib import md5
import ssl
import json

walk_dir = sys.argv[1]
actual_hash = {}
data = {}

def get_md5sum(file_name):
    """
    Calculate the md5sum of file.
    Returns a valid md5sum if successful, None otherwise.
    """
    md5sum = md5()
    block_size = 128 * md5sum.block_size
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                data = f.read(block_size)
                if not data:
                    break
                md5sum.update(data)
        return md5sum.hexdigest()
    except Exception as e:
        ERROR("Failed to calculate md5sum for %s with %s" %
              (file_name, e))
        return None


def dict_compare(d1, d2):
    d1_keys = set(d1.keys())
    d2_keys = set(d2.keys())
    intersect_keys = d1_keys.intersection(d2_keys)
    added = d1_keys - d2_keys
    removed = d2_keys - d1_keys
    modified = {o : (d1[o], d2[o]) for o in intersect_keys if d1[o] != d2[o]}
    same = set(o for o in intersect_keys if d1[o] == d2[o])
    return added, removed, modified, same

with open('../tool/file.json', 'r') as f:
     data = json.load(f)

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir):
for filename in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
    tmp_str = get_md5sum(file_path)
    actual_hash[file_path]= tmp_str

added, removed, modified, same = dict_compare(data, actual_hash)

print "\n\n*******************************"
print "Newly Added Files"
print "*******************************"
if len(added) == 0:
    print "No files are newly added"
else:
    print "\n ".join(str(e) for e in added)


print "\n\n*******************************"
print "Missing Files"
print "*******************************"
if len(removed) == 0:
    print "No files are missing or removed"
else:
    print "\n ".join(str(e) for e in removed)


print "\n\n*******************************"
print "Modified Files"
print "*******************************"
if not modified:
    print "No modified files are found"
else:
    print modified
```

It throws

modified = {o : (d1[o], d2[o]) for o in intersect_keys if d1[o] != d2[o]}
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can i make this work on older versions and also, please suggest improvements on this code. Thanks!

Comment: Dict comprehension is not available in Python 2.6.

Comment: Yeah, thanks but how do i make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
modified = {o : (d1[o], d2[o]) for o in intersect_keys if d1[o] != d2[o]}
```

to this:

```
modified = {}
for o in intersect_keys:
    if d1[o] != d2[o]:
        modified[o] = (d1[o], d2[o])
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work. I have one more question. In modified files, it prints like this currently, {u'./tools/README.txt': ('14049286fe4b33e91f6ff79256b4dcc4', u'e0a79b8e702602c7e78a9b0fbafaf806')}. How do i print so that I get rid of this 'u'

Answer (score 0):

One improvement suggestion, immediately check if d1 is equal to d2, return without unnecessary processing, then carry on with finding out why it is not.

```
def dict_compare(d1, d2):
    if d1 == d2:
        return 0, 0, False, True
    {the rest of your code here}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have one more question. In modified files, it prints like this currently, {u'./tools/README.txt': ('14049286fe4b33e91f6ff79256b4dcc4', u'e0a79b8e702602c7e78a9b0fbafaf806')}. How do i print so that I get rid of this 'u'

Comment: I don't know why you would need to, that has to do with encoding. More can be found here [https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)